# .Textframe VBA Microsoft PowerPoint issue

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, shapes, powerpoint

I'm trying to fix a bug in some code that was written a long time ago by a colleague of mine. Both of us are stumped because until recently everything worked fine:

```
Sub paste3()

Dim oSh As Shape

n = 4
DoEvents
Take2:
On Error GoTo Take2:
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteDefault)(1)
    ' .PasteSpecial returns a ShapeRange; the (1) at the end of the line above
    ' returns the first shape in the range. W/o that, you get a type mismatch error
    ' from trying to assign a range to a shape

With oSh
   ' Set position:
  .Left = 41
  .Top = 57
   ' Set size:
  .Height = 100
  .Width = 700
  .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 11

End With
```

The code fails at the ".TextFrame" line and gives the error "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified value is out of range".

I can't see why it's doing this. Stepping into the macro you see a cell copied from excel and then pasted into Powerpoint as a textbox (oSh).

I've tried changing the size from 11 to 10, 12 etc. just in case it was some mad error with that but no joy.

Here is what the locals box is saying in the editor:
[image]

I don't really understand why this has never thrown an error before as we've been using this macro for over a year with no problems.

Comment: I notice that HasText = False in your screenshot. That suggests that for some reason there's no text in the text frame; that would explain why PPT is barking. Can't set the size of text that's not there.  Have you stepped through the code to watch what happens just before the point where the error occurs?

Comment: Are you certain that the shape that is referenced is something that supports text. That locals snapshot looks something like what a picture shape would have or anything that doesn’t support a textframe.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I saw that as well. It doesn't make sense because I have watched the code through and it definitely copies a cell from Excel and paste's it as a text box in Powerpoint. I can stop the Debug process, move the text box around and edit the text inside it. Finding it fairly odd that HasText = False.

Comment: @ShyamPillai I've tried defining a variant and setting that as the pasted cell, but still the same issue. I don't know if it's a problem with copying a cell from Excel into a textbox in PowerPoint.

Comment: @JamesBaker Aha. When I paste a cell from Excel to PPT, I get a table object, not a text box. A table doesn't have a TextFrame. I'd try adding the text box in PPT programmatically then setting its TextFrame.TextRange.Text property to the value of the Excel cell you're interested in.